# Performance Impact of JSON_encode vs a JSON string

Tags: php, json, performance, performance-testing, processing-efficiency

Hi I am basically trying to gauge the performance impact of creating a nested array structure which is then converted into JSON using json_encode() vs simply writing a string with valid JSON.

The language specifically is PHP, but I am also using python, as well as GO.

out of the two options I would rather create a large nested array structure to add flexibility but because this is being used in a very high traffic environment (100,000+ requests a second) I am concerned of the performance overhead of JSON_encode vs writing a json string.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: As with all performance questions: **benchmark it**. Yes, of course, creating an array and then encoding it in a separate pass is going to be more expensive than just writing a string in most languages. The tricky part however is to "simply write a valid JSON string"; it's not really *that* simple. Figure out whether the alternative is *too slow for you* and whether it's really *simple enough* for you to write JSON by hand. Sometimes splurging on the server with one more CPU core is cheaper than having a programmer hunt bugs for months in their custom JSON encoder.

Comment: If I were to guess I would say that the time spent encoding the data would be negligible compared to network and disk access to the extent that it is not worth your time trying to optimize for it. Which is to say you will spend far longer waiting for a db query to return than any amount of encoding you do with the data post query. As a general rule wait until you have a measurable performance problem before trying to optimize for it. Focus your time on writing clean maintainable readable code instead of optimizing.

Comment: You mention 100,000+ requests a second. Do you expect to get this from a single server? You might get 10k per second if all your data is in memory with no db access but probably not much better than that from a single machine.

Comment: No we expect a fairly large cluster will be required, because of the very high concurrent processing we are looking to maximise capacity per node. All database data is cached in redis periodically and all database writes are queued using rabbitmq and done independently of the requests. Because we expect the volume to significantly increase we are attempting to make decisions now that will ensure the projects viability with much higher requests per second.